# jQuery .done is not called when rendering .json.erb template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am trying to clean up the code by moving the response from create into a view (some helpers are used and this makes sense). However for some reason my js callbacks are never getting called. I am 100% confused so here are my logs and code. Thanks a ton :-)

#### reviews_controller.rb

```
def create
    @review = Review.new(post_params)
    @review.library = @library if @library
    @review.user = current_user
    if !@review.save
        render json: {error_code: "400", message: "Invalid paramaters"}
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to(library_path(@library))}
        format.json {render "create.json"}
    end
end
```

#### libraries.js (loaded on page)

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#new_review").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        var values = form.serialize();
        var url = form.attr("action");
        debugger;
        $.post(url + ".json", values).done(function(data) {
            debugger;
        });
    });
});
```

#### create.json.erb

```
{
    review: <%= @review.to_json %>, 
    average_rating: <%= number_to_human(@library.average_rating) %>
}
```

#### server log

```
Started POST "/libraries/10/reviews.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-16 10:12:18 -0400
Processing by ReviewsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MgB1pj2lQNMgPCknUMP+lc2EWtrp06n1GkaAbrJONJwM//fmY7gI8azvy3IFh9NZfoRysoiVln3vAH+AFzW1QQ==", "review_rating_dispaly"=>"1", "review"=>{"rating"=>"1", "comment"=>""}, "library_id"=>"10"}
  Library Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "libraries".* FROM "libraries" WHERE "libraries"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "reviews" ("comment", "library_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["comment", ""], ["library_id", 10], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-07-16 14:12:18.075609"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-16 14:12:18.075609"]]
   (5.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  SELECT AVG("reviews"."rating") FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."library_id" = ?  [["library_id", 10]]
  Rendered reviews/create.json.erb (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)
```

#### response from server in chrome network logs

```
{
    review: {&quot;id&quot;:37,&quot;rating&quot;:1,&quot;user_id&quot;:1,&quot;library_id&quot;:10,&quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2017-07-16T14:23:25.213Z&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2017-07-16T14:23:25.213Z&quot;}, 
    average_rating: 1.86
}
```

Comment: What's the response you are getting on the network console?

Comment: edited answer to show. It seems to be returning the correct data but `.done` just will not be called :-(

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: shouldn't `done` still be called?

Comment: Most likely it's trying to parse it as JSON and it's failing, so `done` doesn't get called and `fail` is.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to get rails to return valid json?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"` before the row definitions and add `.html_safe` to the json

```
{
    "review": <%= @review.to_json(only: [:comment, :rating]).html_safe %>,
    "average_rating": <%= number_to_human(@library.average_rating) %>
}
```